# Rails Render Content without Navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and rails, and in my layouts folder there is my `_navigation` file. I'm trying to create a "home page" without any navigation.

```
:layout=>false
```

Doesn't include any CSS or any layouts - just the content. I need the styling to show up...

Is there a way to render but ignore the inclusion of the `_navigation` file?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I created a blank layout.

```
:render= layout=>'blank'
```

My blank layout looks like this (I removed the layout code)

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
      %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "App"
      %meta{:content => content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "App", :name => "description"}
        = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
        = javascript_include_tag "application"
        = csrf_meta_tags
        = yield(:head)
  %body{:class => "#{controller_name} #{action_name}",:style=>"padding-top:0px"}
    #main{:role => "main"}
      .container
        .content
          .row
            .span12
              = render 'layouts/messages'
              = yield
          %footer
      / ! end of .container
    / ! end of #main
```

Also note that I modified the body to have `padding-top` of 0px (overriding the bootstrap values)